# jQuery $.fn. function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been making my first tiny jQuery plugin - I was using the javascript with a standard function but decided to bundle it up in to a jquery plugin with a few options.

Here's a slim down version of my jquery code:

```
(function($) {

        $.fn.responsiveNav = function( options ) {

            // Establish our default settings
            var settings = $.extend({
                selector         : '.responsive-nav'
            }, options);

            $( " " + settings.selector + " ul li" ).has( "ul" ).each(function() {
                $(this).addClass('responsive-nav-dropdown');
            });
            $( ".responsive-nav-dropdown" ).click(function() {
                $("ul",this).toggle();
            });

        }

    }(jQuery));
```

I'm then calling this function in document ready by doing the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    responsiveNav();
});
```

But this is leading to a function not defined error. I'm guessing that this is some sort of scoping issue but I haven't been able to find anything to help me rectify the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.fn` construct is used to define a method on the jQuery object. Therefore you need to use your plugin like this:

```
$('#myElement').responsiveNav();
```

Alternatively you can make it a method off the jQuery variable itself:

```
$.responsiveNav = function( options ) { // note: no .fn
    // your code...
}

// to call it:
$.responsiveNav({ /* options */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - so the $.fn construct doesnt NEED to be used for every plugin? and in my case it may be better to make the method off the jQuery variable itself?

Comment: @user319940 for `$.example` use `$.example = function (method) { ... };` and for `$('#something').example();` use `$.fn.example = function (method) { ... };` Don't forget return `this` in this function!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with passing the selector as an option as opposed to doing something like: $('.responsive-nav-container').responsiveNav(); ?

Comment: Late answer, but there's nothing to stop you doing it, but it's completely backwards to how jQuery is supposed to work, so I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($) {
   ///

    })(jQuery);
```

And not

```
(function($) {
   ///

    }(jQuery));
```

Another thing: don't pass selector in setting. If so, what is the utility of jQuery.

The Jquery object in your plugin is `this`:

```
.each(function(i,e) {}) 
// known that e is the current element in your loop
    $.fn.responsiveNav = function( options ) {
        var this=that; 
        var settings = $.extend({selector: '.responsive-nav'}, options);
    $(that).has( "ul" ).each(function(i,e) {
        $(e).addClass('responsive-nav-dropdown');
    });
    $( ".responsive-nav-dropdown" ).click(function() {
        $("ul",this).toggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like:

```
$("selector").responsiveNav();
```